# Error in opening recorded jmeter script in non GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

I tried running a recorded jmeter script from non GUI mode because jmeter showed memory heap error. 
I entered the following command in the cmd prompt-

```
C:\Users\user name\Documents\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin>jmeter -n -t C:\Users\user name\Documents\Jmeter ABC\Jmeter ABC_test\recorded script\recorded_v2.jmx
```

I keep getting this error line from the prompt -

```
An error occurred: Unknown arg: name\Documents\Jmeter  
errorlevel=1
```

I followed this solution but that did not help- https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/16442

I did not understand the error. What does it mean? Any other steps that I should follow?

Comment: Put the jmx file in the JMeter bin folder and then run the command
`C:\Users\user name\Documents\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin>jmeter -n -t recorded_v2.jmx`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

put the path in quotes as it contain spaces:

```
C:\Users\user name\Documents\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin>jmeter -n -t "C:\Users\user name\Documents\Jmeter ABC\Jmeter ABC_test\recorded script\recorded_v2.jmx"
```

Answer (score 0):

Type jmeter bin path in CLI and type

```
jmeter.bat -n -t "xyz.jmx path"
```

with double quotes.

Example:-

```
H:\>cd "H:\New folder\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin"


H:\New folder\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin>jmeter.bat -n -t"H:\New folder\apache-jmeter-4.0\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\examples\xyz.jmx"
```

Comment: Please add some explanation